# Returning information from a Hashmap

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Basically what I'm trying to do is store two values into a hashmap, i've tried a dictionary and failed with that as-well, anyhow, here we go.

```
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> dropTable = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

Then, in my code I have this

```
    for(int npc = 0; npc < 10; npc++){
        dropTable.put(npc, Constants.itemDrops[npc][1]);
    }
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is save the values in this manner (With the ItemID being what is returned in the itemDrops array

```
<ArrayIndex, ItemID>
```

How,ever when I try to return this information, i can't figure it out.

Here is how I attempted returning this value

```
        for(int i = 0; i < dropTable.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("NPC: " + dropTable.get((Integer)i));
    }
```

However, that returns null, and looking at it, it wont give me what I need.

How would I go about retrieving the Key/Value separately from the HashMap based on the Index of the HashMap? (If Hashmaps even have Index's, that's what I'm under the impression of)

===============
My idea of a hashmap.

```
<Integer>, <Integer> Index: 0
<Integer>, <Integer> Index: 1
etc...
```

Comment: there is no way to do so with hashmap

Comment: Could you provide a method that this is possible in?

Answer (score 0):

HashMaps are unsorted, do not have indexes and the order features are returned during iteration is not guaranteed to be the order of insertion.

There are other Map objects available which provide some of these features. TreeMap is sorted for example.

All Maps provide a method keySet() which provides the set of Keys in an iterator and a similar values() Collection iterating over these objects is likely to provide the sort of behavour you wish.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to aks, is a hashmap realy the data structure you need?

If not not then just use a simple [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and use its `get(index)` method!

If Yes then you could use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) implmentation - such as [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) -  that preserves the insert/put order. Then you can call [values()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29) of that map and iterate over it using enhanced for-loop, or probably also create a List and passing it the collection reurned if you need index access.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get a your objects according to an index - what you are really looking for is an **[`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)** - which allows access by index, and is basically a [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array).

If you want to objects "attached" to the same index, you can use 2 ArrayLists (one for each type of object) - or use a [`Pair`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/apirefs.1111/e13403/oracle/javatools/util/Pair.html) (from apache commons) as an element in the arraylist.

Comment: The original method I was using involved a pair of array lists, I just wanted to try to simplify it without using what seemed like hundreds of variables